# How do I reference the first table in a Multi Table From?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, concatenation

I am attempting to use the Multi Table From statement to compare all records in two different filtered views of the same table. Results seem to be what I am expecting, however when I try and join another table using a concat() to create a combo key SSMS returns the following error.

Error:

> The multi-part identifier "a.ccustno1" could not be bound.

Example Code:

```
Select *
  From (Select ccustno AS 'ccustno1' 
          From table1 
         Where orderdate = cast(Getdate() AS Date)) a, 
               (Select ccustno AS 'ccustno2' 
                  From table1 
                 Where (orderdate >= dateadd(day, 0, getdate()))) b
           Join table2 c 
             ON c.custkey = concat(a.ccustno1, b.ccustno2)
```

Context and extra question:

For the results I am trying to generate a list of all customers in the first filtered view inline with all customers in the second filtered view so that I can add the third table which details their relative distance from each other. The first table is a list of orders filtered for today (first view) and after today (second view). The second table uses lat and long to calculate radial distance and is filtered by how far we are willing to travel for extra orders by county. I want to use the locations of today's orders to tell me which other existing orders we could reasonably deliver today for efficiency.

Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: I've posted an answer which should *run* but I'm not sure the logic is sound. Would you be able to add some sample data and expected results to your question please?

Comment: I was thinking similar logic, but after writing the query thought "surely that can't be right". Glad I'm not the only one @Damien_The_Unbeliever. :)

Comment: On a sidenote: single quotes are delimiters for string literals, not for names. Standard SQL uses double quotes for names; SQL Server uses brackets instead (e.g. `[ccustno1]`). And as `ccustno1` is a valid name, you don't need any delimiters at all.

Comment: I did not realize that about the quotes. Sometimes it seemed like it needed them even if the name contained no spaces, but that may just be me. I appreciate the help. Always good to learn this better. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use comma joins. They happen in an unpredictable order compared with explicit joins, in this case the system is attempting to perform the join between `b` and `c` *before* it applies the (comma) cross join between `a` and the result of joining `b` and `c`.

Use an explicit cross join instead:

```
Select *
From (Select ccustno AS ccustno1 
      From table1 
     Where orderdate = cast(Getdate() AS Date)) a
       cross join
           (Select ccustno AS ccustno2 
              From table1 
             Where (orderdate >= dateadd(day, 0, getdate()))) b
       Join table2 c 
         ON c.custkey = concat(a.ccustno1, b.ccustno2)
```

(I'm still not sure that final join condition makes *sense*, because I wouldn't expect to be able to take two customer numbers (assuming I'm interpreting your names right) and concatenate them together to make a customer key)

Comment: That is what I am trying to do. Set every instance of an order today in line with every instance of an order after. This will have a multiplicative effect on the number of rows. So 1 order today and 2 orders tomorrow would result in 2 rows in the final with the first order being listed twice in line with the two orders for after today. From that I then want to use the concat to make the combo key representing the customer number from today's order and the customer number from one of tomorrow's orders as the key to link to table2.

Comment: So, I did try the Cross Join, which I have very little experience with and I see that it is the new way to join tables in the way i wanted. However, I am not clear on how I can provide aliases for fields in that format.

Comment: I did mark your solution as accepted both because the Cross Join suggestion and you did provide me with information that lead to a solution. Your point about the order of operations suggested it to me. I simply encapsulated the multi from within a single from. 

Select *

From (Select *  From (Select ccustno AS 'ccustno1' From table1 
         Where orderdate = cast(Getdate() AS Date)) a, 
               (Select ccustno AS 'ccustno2' From table1 
                 Where (orderdate >= dateadd(day, 0, getdate()))) b) a

Join table2 c ON c.custkey = concat(a.ccustno1, b.ccustno2)